# Staggered entries in tabular environment

Tags: tables

I am trying to create a table such that the entries in the left furthermost column are entered normally, but the entries in the column to the right must be staggered in a way such that one entry on the right corresponds to two entries on the left. Thus, the entries on the right must be staggered down so that they appear between the entries on the left. I dont have a tex example because I have no idea how to do this in latex, and my searches online haven't been successful. I have a link to pdf which I am converting to a tex file where this problem arises.

http://www.physics.brocku.ca/Courses/2P32/LectureNotes/ -- page 8 the table at the bottom.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `multirow` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{cc}
0000 & \multirow{2}{1cm}{1}\\
0001 & \multirow{2}{1cm}{1}\\
0011 & \multirow{2}{1cm}{1}\\
0010 & \multirow{2}{1cm}{1}\\
0110 & 
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```